# WIX Installer. Only check condition based on feature

Tags: wix

I have a condition to check if IIS is installed, but i only want to perform this check if the Server feature will be installed, not the Client. I tried adding Levels to the features but I am not able to find the correct syntax for this by guessing or other posts and was hoping for some assistance?  I am using WIX 3.10.

thanks

```
<Condition Message="Install requires IIS 7 or higher version.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR (IISMAJORVERSION AND (IISMAJORVERSION >= "#7" OR IISMAJORVERSION = "#10"))]]>
</Condition>


  <Feature Id='Feature.Server' Title='Receiver' Description='Server' Level='2'>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id='Server.Components'/>
    <ComponentRef Id='Server.Configuration' />
    <ComponentRef Id=' Server_VirtualDirComponent'/>
  </Feature>

  <Feature Id='Feature.Client' Title='Client' Description='Client' Level='1'>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id=' Client.Components'/>
    <ComponentRef Id='Client.Configuration' />
    <ComponentRef Id='Client_VirtualDirComponent'/>
  </Feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [conditional syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368012(v=vs.85).aspx) `&Feature.Server = 2 OR !Feature.Server > 2` indicates the server feature either is installed already, or will not be installed.

If it's predetermined by the MSI whether the feature is installed, you should be fine to just replace the "Installed" part of your condition. If it's selectable by the user you will probably need to move the whole thing to a type 19 custom action, scheduled for some time after the user selects the features, since the launch conditions are evaluated before then. (I could be wrong on this part, test it both ways to see what works).